# How to get index (position of an item e.g 1,2,3...) of dropped element li in droppable jquery?

Tags: jquery, droppable

I am Dragging an element and dropping in droppable area . In drop function() i am sending data to be saved in sql server database.I want to get the index of dropped (target, not source)element like: first li element will be 1, then second will be 2...and so on.

I tried  sidemenu.Position=

$( "#selected" ).length: its returning 1 for every dropped element.

$(event.target).index(): its returning 3 for every dropped element.

$(ui.placeholder).index()

I am using jquery-3.3.1.js,jquery-ui.js,jquery-ui.css.

Here is my code:

```
$('#divSelected').droppable({

            accept: "#available li",
            drop: function (event, ui) {    
                 //draggable.clone().appendTo(droppable);
                 $("#selected").append($("<li>/li>").text(ui.draggable.text()));
                 var sidemenu = {};
                 sidemenu.Position = ?

             }
});
```

Comment: `$(event.target).index()` works correctly for me when I try with a project I used `droppable` for, so perhaps there's another problem here. Also you're missing the closing `<` in `$("<li>/li>")` - `$("<li />")` would also work.

Comment: @user7290573 I have $("<li></li>") in my code. May be while pasting it got deleted. And yes, may be there is other problem because i tried $(event.target).index() again , its giving 3 everytime.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a JSFiddle?